# How to replace multiple words/special characters from statement in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have statement

```
"Mumbai & Pune are big cities in Maharashtra. Mumbai > Pune."
```

I need a query to replace :
`"&"` as `'AND'` and 
`">"` as `'GREATER THAN'` in a single query in oracle.

Required output is

```
Mumbai AND Pune are big cities in Maharashtra. Mumbai GREATER THAN Pune.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace

```
Select replace(replace(your_string,'&',' AND '),'>',' GREATER THAN ') FROM TABLE
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Nested `replace`:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Mumbai & Pune are big cities in Maharashtra. Mumbai>Pune.' from dual)
  3  select replace(replace(col, '&', 'AND'),
  4                              '>', ' GREATER THAN ') result
  5  from test;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mumbai AND Pune are big cities in Maharashtra. Mumbai GREATER THAN Pune.

SQL>
```